# deleting a line after selecting the desired line on clicking a button kinetic js

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

```
var line = new Kinetic.Line({ points: [415, 115,617,234], stroke: 'gray', tension: 2});
line.addEventListener('click',function(e){ 
debugger; 
// alert(e.x+'.'+ e.y); 
// popup; 
});
```

On clicking the line it should be selected.on clicking other place expect line it should be deselected.after selecting the line if i pressed a delete button the line should get destroyed how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact as your requirement, but you double click on line, line will be removed from layer

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/68jfxvdm/) is demo.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [73, 70, 340, 23, 450, 60, 500, 20],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 15,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
      });
redLine.on("dblclick",function(){
        this.destroy();
        layer.draw(); 
    });

layer.add(redLine);
stage.add(layer);
```

Comment: can we get stage.find('elementbycolor=red') is it possible.i have 100 shapes each with each shape with random color i want all shapes  with specific color by query#wisdmlabs

Comment: Yes, when you create shape then add id attribute to shape like
`var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [73, 70, 340, 23, 450, 60, 500, 20],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 15,
        id:"red"
      });`
and then get it as `var shape = stage.find('#red')[0];`

[here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shape-by-id-with-kineticjs/) you can understand better